# Write the powershell script using runbook to enable the soft delete option for all keyVault in automated way

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-keyvault, runbook

As per my understanding keyvault names are globally unique and also secrets as well as
I won't be able to reuse the keyvault that exists in the soft deleted state
I am having the multiple keyvaults, after deleting multiple keyvaluts it is moving to softdelete state

I want to enable the soft delete option automatically,
If someone came and acciedently delete my keyvalut i can be able to grant the access permissions to recover the secrets
Every time I cannot go to the portal and enable the soft delete option for the keyvault manually i want this in automated way

How can we write the playbook using powershell to automate the soft delete option for all keyvaults
I have searched in the net and find this microsoft  [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/soft-delete-change) but didnot get any related information related to automation to get the results

Can any one help me to do this I will really appreciated

Thanks in advance $ have a good day with nice answer  :)-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I tried to create the runbook using PowerShell for keyvault in my environment and got the below results*

*I have created the automation account to use the runbook*

[image]

*Created the runbook and wrote the PowerShell script for soft delete*

```
    #soft delete option for single vault
    Connect-AzAccount
    Get-AzKeyVault -VaultName "XXXXXX" 
    $vaultId  =  (Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name "recovery-services"  -ResourceGroupName 'XXXXX'.id)   
    (Get-AzRecoveryServicesVaultProperty -VaultID $vaultId).SoftDeleteFeatureState  
    
    
    #soft delete option for multiple keyvaults
    $vaults  = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault
    foreach($vault  in  $vaults)  {   
    $properties  = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVaultProperty -VaultId $vault.Id    
    if($properties.SoftDeleteFeatureState -eq 'Enabled')  {    
    Write-Host "Soft delete option is enabled"  $properties.SoftDeleteFeatureState "for"  $vault.Name "`n" `    
    -ForeGroundColor Green    
    }  else  {    
    Write-Host "Soft delete option is enabled"  $properties.SoftDeleteFeatureState "for"  $vault.Name "`n" `    
    -ForeGroundColor Red   
    }
    }
```

*Saved my script and published, and I run my script
when I check the job its succeeded and the status is running*

[image]

*When I check the keyvault the auto soft delete got enabled*

[image]

*Added the schedule to run automatically for particular period of time*

[image]